# Why account balance can decrease when gasPrice is 0 and msg.value is 0?

Tags: truffle, gas, testrpc, ganache

It also spends pretty large amount, which doesn't seem to be related to gasUsed

Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Test {
    bool i;
    function hello() public {
        i = true;
    }
}
```

Test script:

```
const Test = artifacts.require("Test");

contract('Test', async (accounts) => {
    it('should pass', async () => {
        const operator = accounts[0];
        const alice    = accounts[1];
        let testInstance = await Test.new({from: operator});
        const before = web3.eth.getBalance(alice);
        const receipt = await testInstance.hello({from: alice, value: 0});
        const after = web3.eth.getBalance(alice);
        assert.equal(before.toString(), after.toString());
    });
});
```

Ganache launched as

```
# ganache-cli --gasPrice=0 --gasLimit=7e7
```

Output:

```
# truffle test
Using network 'development'.



  Contract: Test
41672
    1) should pass
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (1s)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: Test should pass:
     AssertionError: expected '100000000000000000000' to equal '99995832800000000000'
      at Context.it (test/withdrawalFunctions.js:16:16)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

Comment: Check the transaction receipt, it might be that a non zero gas price was used instead, or you can force a 0 gas price in the transaction options `{ from: alice, value: 0, gasPrice: 0 }`.

Comment: That was exactly the case! For some reason the contract methods use gas price different from `web3.eth.gasPrice`